# Bypass Options -Indexes in htaccess to view content

Tags: websites, htaccess

My professor gave me this task and said "Easy" about it!

I don't know how serious is he!

The task :

I have a directory for example
[www.example.com/items](http://www.example.com/items)

The "items" directory contents :
AGDVGCVFVVCVGDD.txt
Dgcbvvhvbhvbbbb.txt

And the main .htaccess has "Options -Indexes"

All I know is that the directory url is [www.example.com/items](http://www.example.com/items)

How can I view the txt files inside it without knowing their names?

Comment: use `/./` perhaps?

Comment: I've tried it, it makes 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.